# colorSurface and background collides on NavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

I am observing some magic that I cannot explain. Ideally I should not set background on NavigationView; configuration on styles should be sufficient, but somehow it is not.

this is my setup:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:background="#2A2E43"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

and on my theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorSurface">"#2A2E43"</item>
....
</style>
```

I have tried last alpha and beta versions on material:

```
versions.material = "1.2.0-beta01"
```

The result is following: [image: Original Background]

Color actually does not match what I have specified, so I played around, and changed background color by one bit as `android:background="#2A2E43"`, so the outcome is surprising as:

[image: Background color #2A2E43]

I don't know what the heck is going on around, why this happens but when `colorSurface` and `background` matches, NavigationView acts weird and draws own colors. Please help me understand what is going on, and how to fix it. (I don't want to put colors different by a bit.)

*Note: I have put designer screenshots, but same is observed on device as well.*

Comment: which version of material components are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti added to question.

Comment: It's not happening for me I mean even I put same color for both surface and bg it works fine ...

Comment: maybe I played with theme too much. Will create an empty project and try 